# How to go back from user '> to user=> after you enter a wrong command in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

What I have tried that works would be exiting psql using `\q` and logging in again using `psql -d postgres -U user`, but that's kind of a hassle.

So my question would be, is there a better way to go back to the `user=>` from `user'>` because with the latter you won't be able to use any psql commands.

Comment: `\p` is to print to stdout, I'm guessing you mean `\q`. `user'>` means you have a missing `'` in the command. The easiest way to fix is to enter the `'` at the prompt and then `\r` to reset the buffer.

Comment: Ah yes thanks for pointing that out. I did mean ```\q``` instead of ```\p```. I will try your recommendation and get back to you.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did as you told me and the user'> became user(> after that, I entered \r and the result was Query buffer reset (cleared). which did bring me back to user=> and solving my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompt `dbname'>` indicates that you started a string literal (entered a single quote) but didn't finish it. You can get out of that by

1. closing the string literal and resetting the query buffer:

   ```
   '\r
   ```
2. hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or whatever sends the SIGINT signal on your terminal